# Convert integral equation to differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand how to transform an integral equation like:

$$f(x)^{-n}+\int_{-\infty}^\infty  f(y)f(x-y)\,dy=0$$

for integer $n\geq1$ and some appropriate function $f(x)$ to a differential equation. Roughly I know that I should try to take a derivative with respect to $x$, but then what? Any suggestions?

Comment: If you wish to solve it you can use Fourier transform

Comment: Let 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}dk$$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)f(x-y)dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(q)\hat{f}(k)e^{i(k-q)y}e^{iqx}dydkdq=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta(k-q)\hat{f}(q)\hat{f}(k)e^{iqx}dkdq=$$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}^{2}(k)e^{ikx}dk$$
And the equation becomes
$$\hat{f}(k)=-1$$
Hence
$$f(x)=-\sqrt{2\pi}\delta(k)$$

Comment: I don't see any sense in turning it into ode

Comment: @KirylPesotski ok, I see, my choice of example was not too fortunate, let me change it a bit to make it more interesting!

Comment: @KirylPesotski how about this one? With inverse power of function.

Comment: Taking the derivative doesn't really work in your example, since the variable x is in the integrand. You can, however, interpret the integral as a convolution of $f(x)$ with itself. Then you can take the Fourier transform to convert the convolution to a product

Comment: @Dylan unfortunately, the fourier transform of $f(x)^{-n}$, which we would also need to consider, is not guaranteed to be defined. Any way to still proceed?

Comment: I don't know. But I have a good feeling that this can't be turned into a differential equation.